# why UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled() always return NO?

Tags: ios, uiaccessibility

In my app, for default behaviour the method UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled() return NO, and that OK. Unfortunately, even when i changed in Settings > Accessibility > Guided Access > Guided Access to YES, it's still return NO.
Why is that ?

Comment: did you manage to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You have not "enabled" it yet. I know it sounds odd, but your app doesn't know about it until you triple tap the home button and start it for your app. Configuring it is not enough. They should have probably had two states, enabled (configured) and activated.