# Stranger Behavior with UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled Bool - SWIFT

Tags: swift, guided-access

My app wants to recognize whether or not the user has gone into guided access mode.

I currently have a NSNotification setup which triggers a boolean provided by apple but for some reason it is always providing a false negative.

```
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter() .addObserver(self, selector: #selector(guidedAccessChanged), name: UIAccessibilityGuidedAccessStatusDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

will trigger the following method

```
    func guidedAccessChanged () {

//        NSLog(@"Accessabilitiy enabled: %@", UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled() ? @"YES" : @"NO");

        print("Accessabilitiy enabled: \(UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled() ? "YES" : "NO" )")

        if (!UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled()){

            print("guided access Off")

        }
        else{
            print("guided access On")

        }

    }
```

But for some reason the logs are returning

> guided access Off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function and notification should reflect whether Guided Access is **enabled and active** for your app, not necessarily when it is on in Settings.

So if Guided Access is on in Settings, I don't know of public API that is going to let you know, but if it is currently running (i.e. the user has triple-tapped the home button to explicitly enter Guided Access for your app, set their preferred options, and tapped start) `UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled()` should return `true`. But only then.

See the comments on the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663481/detect-or-react-to-guided-access)

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36408265/why-uiaccessibilityisguidedaccessenabled-always-return-no).

Comment: Interesting that Apple's documentation on this function says that the return value is "true if the user has enabled Guided Access in Settings; otherwise, false."  It makes no mention about being active or inactive based on the home button triple-click.  Is this a documentation error?

Comment: @ChristopherWhidden Not positive, but this appears to be what other sources indicate.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, all though not the answer I wanted to hear but as your answer is accurate I have given the bounty. Maybe I will raise this issue with apple